# PostgreSQL full text search doesn't work in some case (Django)

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

I notice that in django when there is a sentence containing `PLAZA/MASTERPIECE` then when we search masterpiece I can't find this sentence. Is this a limitation of PostgreSQL full text search. Or how to solve this?

```
finalquery = SearchQuery("keyword")
vector = SearchVector('thefieldIwanttosearch')
self.search_results = self.search_results.annotate(search=vector).filter(search=finalquery).annotate(rank=SearchRank(vector, finalquery))
```

Is there any document about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is all documented.

When you write `filter(search=finalquery)` you're not specifying a [lookup type](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups).

> As a convenience when no lookup type is provided (like in `Entry.objects.get(id=14)`) the lookup type is assumed to be `exact`.

So you're filtering on an exact match for "masterpiece". What you probably want is [`contains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#contains) or [`icontains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#icontains).